# Compatibility between versions of GNU Make

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, makefile

I have been using GCC for many years to compile ARM projects developed using Eclipse. I have decided it is time to update the tools I'm using.

I have been using a version of GCC 'cribbed' from CodeSourcery, but I have upgraded to the latest version from http://gnutoolchains.com/arm-eabi/.  All works well, except for Make:

The CodeSourcery folder includes a version named cs-make.exe, dated 30/04/2013. I have downloaded a newer version of GCC/GDB from http://gnutoolchains.com/arm-eabi/ into a folder that I named SysGCC.  It contains the app make.exe, dated 27/05/2015.

I have modified my makefile to use SysGCC and it compiles correctly.  However, if I then modify my project to run make.exe instead of cs-make.exe the console shows the following errors:

> ```
> make -j -k all 
> make: *** No rule to make target `IO.o', needed by `Display.elf'.
> make: *** No rule to make target `XTPcommon.o', needed by `Display.elf'.
> make: *** No rule to make target `DisplayCommon.o', needed by `Display.elf'.
> .
> .
> ```

The contents of my makefile are quite complex, and include the following:

> ```
> %.o : %.c makefile
>     $(COMPILE) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(OUTPUT_FOLDER)/$@
>     $(COMPILE) -MM $(CFLAGS) $< > $(OUTPUT_FOLDER)/$(addsuffix .d, $(notdir $(basename $@)))
> ```

Since they build correctly with `cs-make.exe` I can see no reason why they shouldn't build with `make.exe`.  So, what's going wrong?

Comment: I'd post your entire makefile. Also, I see `-j` [parallel], so leave that off (i.e. you may need more dependencies for parallel build). And, what is the _exact_ command you're using (e.g.) `make all`. Can you do `make clean`? Also, please _edit_ your question to revise it rather than answering it. It is okay to answer your own question _if_ you actually have an answer for it [most people don't usually unless the answer would exceed 30,000 chars]

Comment: If you run `make.exe --version` and `cs-make.exe --version`, what do you get?  Based on your extension here, you're on Windows (you should be clear about that).  There are multiple ways GNU make can be built on Windows so it can be quite confusing (due to case sensitive/insensitive differences, drive letter support, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your responses.

I spent many frustrating hours trying different combinations of GCC, OpenOCD, JTag drivers and Eclipse plug-ins. I have numerous build versions of a project that all work with my previous toolchain and I tried copying various of these into the project I use to test the new toolchain.

I eventually found the solution. I had somehow managed to corrupt my project to use source files from one build version and a makefile from another version, and there were incompatibility issues between them.

The symptoms were very deceptive and led me up various blind alleys. I still can't understand why it worked with one version of make but not with the other.

When I corrected the project everything worked correctly.